# How to use kNN function in R

Tags: r, knn

I ned to run a knn on my data set ( I tried to use dput() to show data set but it doesn't come up in format summary() so unsure how to share it).
I have used the following code

```
library(caret)
library(class)
set.seed(123)
ind <- createDataPartition(user_col$Nscore, p=0.7,list=FALSE)
training_data <- user_col[1:942,,1 ]
testing_data <- user_col[943:1884,,1 ]
model <- knn(training_data, testing_data, training_data,k=1)
predictions <- as.factor(model)
confusionMatrix(predictions, testing_data[,5])
```

It stops running at model<- ..... with this error

Error in knn(training_data, testing_data, training_data, k = 1) :  'train' and 'class' have different lengths

I have looked in the environment and both training_data and testing_data are the same sizes so not sure where the error is.

Comment: Check `?knn` for `cl` param description and example, `cl` should be *"factor of true classifications of training set"*  , `cl <- factor(c(rep("s",25), rep("c",25), rep("v",25)))` for 3 species in irisi3 dataset
`

Comment: I have 9 variables and 1885 entries in my dataset so unsure how to use this in what I am doing, and it will only run if I specify a column in the data set in the ind<- createDataPartition line

Comment: Number of variables (columns) doesn't really matter, though the `cl` length should match the number of observations (rows) in training data, `nrow(training_data) == length(cl)` , right now the `cl` length is `nrow(training_data) * ncol(train)` .  And every single element in `cl` vector should define the class of matching observation in training data.